# Codeigniter MY_Model by Jamie and querying by with relations

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-base-model

I have the following relationship.

```
Profile
---------------------------------------
id profile_image_id otherdetails
---------------------------------------
1   22             ---
---------------------------------------  

   media
----------------------------------------------
id profile_id path                type
----------------------------------------------
22  1         /exes/lod.png       profile_image
----------------------------------------------
```

Profile has media.
Media is a collection of image paths. and has a column named 'type' //

I want to load all profile with media type ='profile_image';

i want to produce something like below:

```
select * from profile 
inner join with media
where media.type ='smthing';
```

..load models

```
$this->profile->with('media')->get_by('type','profile_image') ;; 
// runs on profile model than media model.
```

**this doesn't work**

I have seen the [documentation](https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model) but i can't get a clue.

Any thing you have done previously similar to this ? Thanks

Comment: Can you please update your question with table structure

Comment: Eloquent doesn't handle relationship queries right out of the box, you need to use some [db queries](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/eloquent-order-by-related-table?page=1).

Comment: dude this not eloquent ? is it ?

Comment: So you need to make a CI eloquent query Am I right @danielad

Comment: Provide a link to the documentation of this "Jamie Model" plugin/library

Comment: i like it and it been a long way since , the whole project relies on it man

Comment: I never used it before, so I cant say to not use it, but cant you use regular CI queries at the same time?

Comment: Please dont down vote this becuse , you have no idea that how future use can be benefited from this , little documented project.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong then this will help you.

```
$this->db->select('p.*');
$this->db->from('profile p');
$this->db->join('media m','p.id = m.profile_id','left');
$this->db->where('m.type','profile_image');
$result = $this->db->get()->result_array();
print_r($result);
```

Comment: i want the MY_MODEL style of accessing.

Comment: Then provide link to your **MY_MODEL style**

Comment: i did on my question the documentation text

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution of course its CI in combination of some helpers with MY_MODEL class.

This a customize solution even in the future , thanks to **michail1982**

```
public function with_media($type='profile_image') {
  $this->_database->join('medias',$this->_table.
     '.'.$this->primary_key.' = medias.profile_id')->where('medias.type', $type);
}
```